# Three player combinatorial game - minimizing communication between Alice and Bob

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, information-theory, monty-hall

Consider the following game between three parties: Alice, Bob and a Referee. The game starts with $n$ closed boxes. For some fixed $k<n$ known to all parties, the Referee freely chooses $k$ distinct boxes and places a prize inside each of them. Alice sees the Referee do this and thus, she knows which boxes have a prize. Bob now enters the room. He can talk to Alice, then choose one box and if this box has a prize, he can keep it.

What is the smallest number of bits of information that Alice needs to convey to Bob such that Bob is guaranteed to win a prize?

The naive strategy is for Alice to pick a prize-containing box at random and give the ID of this box to Bob. This costs $\log n$ bits of information since she picks one box out of $n$ choices. But given that there are $k$ choices and any of them would do the job, can Alice and Bob win the game with less than $\log n$ bits of communication? If yes, what should their strategy be?

EDIT: I am happy to assume the Referee is not adversarial if that admits a better strategy for Alice and Bob.

Comment: Does Bob know $k$? Does Alice have to commit to a number of bits?  For example, they could agree that if she sends just $1$, Bob should open box $1$.  This will work some fraction of the time.

Comment: @RossMillikan Bob knows $k$ - I have added this to the question now. However, Bob has to win the game with certainty, not just some fraction of the time

Comment: I was thinking that if Bob knows $k$ you should be able to do it in $\log_2 n - \log _2 k$ bits, but I don't have a strategy that works.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a "negative" result under these assumptions:

1. The game is deterministic, i.e. all 3 have no access to any randomizer (dice etc).
2. The referee is adversarial and knows Alice & Bob's strategy.
3. There is only 1 round of interaction between Alice & Bob.  So Bob doesn't even need to ask his question (since it's deterministic anyway) and can simply walk into the room and hears Alice's single answer, which is $b$-bits long.

Under these assumptions, the result is IMHO negative: $b$ must satisfy $k + 2^b > n$, or equivalently, $b \ge \log_2(n-k+1)$.

Reason: each of the $2^b$ possible answers deterministically maps to one box.  So if $k + 2^b \le n$ the adversary can place all prizes in boxes which correspond to none of the possible answers.

I consider this a "negative" result because this shows the "obvious" strategy to be optimal.  (The obvious strategy being: eliminate $k-1$ boxes before hand and then just encode the remaining $n-k+1$, since at least one of these must contain a prize.  This is equivalent to the lowest-ID strategy of @leonbloy, which eliminates the highest $k-1$ boxes.)

---

In fact, I think assumption #3 is not needed.  Suppose Alice & Bob can interact for multiple rounds, i.e. Bob asks a question, Alice answers, then based on the answer Bob chooses what question to ask in the next round.  Some of the answers can be long, some can be short.

However, if we use worst-case (not "average" in some sense) total number of bits as the criterion, it is still true that the $b$ bits encode a particular sequence of questions and answers.  (Remember: Bob has no access to random bits, so his questions are deterministically based on Alice's previous answers).  Thus with $b$ total bits it is still only possible to encode $2^b$ different boxes at most.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious strategy is: Alice picks the lowest box id and sends it. There are $n-k+1$ possible values, hence the information content is at most $\log(n-k+1)$

Actually, if we assume that the $k$ boxes are chosen at random, the distribution of the picked one will not be uniform, hence the information content will be less than that.

The pmf of the smallest member of a $(n,k)$ selection, indexed from $j=0\cdots n-k$ is

$$P(j)= \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}\binom{n-j}{k}\frac{k}{n-j}$$

I'm not sure if the entropy of this distribution can be put in a simple form.

Edited: for large $n$ the entropy (in nats) of the above gives me the following not-too-illuminating expression:

$$H\approx \frac{k}{n} \frac{e^{-k/n}}{1-e^{-k/n}} - \log(1- e^{-k/n})$$

For large $n$ and $k$, with $k/n \to 0$, this behaves as $\log(n)-\log(k)+ O(1)$

Comment: Thank you - it's an interesting answer! I will leave this question open a bit longer to see if there's any other way to think about the problem.

Comment: Why is playing uniformly at random the correct response to this strategy of A? Can't one skew placement to flatten the law of the minimum a bit?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 (If I understand what you mean) If the Referee is evil and knows Alice strategy, then, yes, he should not choose uniformly, but favour the biggest values. 
Then, the bound $\log(n-k)$ would remain, but not the rest. I'm not sure if we could devise a general strategy that works better than that for any probability distribution of the selected subset. Interesting.

Comment: Basically yes, except I wouldn't say evil. I just wanted to point out that there's a game theoretic/minimax aspect to the question. I guess the immediate idea would be to sample the smallest point from some law $\Pi$, and then sample the remaining uniformly at random from $[X_{min}, n]$ (taking $\Pi$ uniform on $[1:n-k]$ would take us to $\log(n-k)$). The trouble of course is that $A$ will change strategy to respond to $\Pi$ - e.g. this $\Pi$ will skew the law of the largest filled box, so $A$ might switch to reporting the max index. It's subtle to see where the balance lies.

Comment: Actually, wait - here's a referee strategy that shows that any strategy that is based on $A$ reporting on the basis of a single marginal incurs costs $\log(n-k)$ - pick the median filled box uniformly from $[k/2:n-k/2],$ and place all the balls in a consecutive bunch. Then the law of any order statistic is uniform on a set of size $n-k$.

Comment: BTW this is not a good strategy for the referee, since the response by $A$ can be to grid the space at resolution $k$, and observe that at least one of the centers of this grid must be occupied if the referee places things this way, and so be able to communicate with $\log(n/k)$ bits.

Comment: Just wanna point out that: Since Bob can talk, if he has access to random bits then he can call out a random permutation and then Alice gives the lowest in that permutation.  This way the referee cannot "skew" the distribution, since they don't know a-priori what Bob's random permutation will be.

Answer (score 0):

What @antkam suggested is a good starting point, but not entirely correct (according to me). The question asks how long the *longest* message should be that Alice gives to Bob so that they are guaranteed to win. If we admit messages with at most $b$ bits, we actually have $2^{b+1}-1$ messages since they could also be shorter.

Now lets go deeper on @antkam's point. Assume his third assumption holds. Now for each of the $2^{b+1}-1$ messages Alice can give, Bob needs to have a response. If this response were non-deterministic, then just select an arbitrary (but fixed) response from Bob's considerations, since *each* possible decision of Bob must lead to a prize. Now if $2^{b+1} -1+ k \leq n$ we see that we have a problem if the referee chooses the $k$ boxes that this strategy cannot reach. For this it is sufficient that the referee plays each of the possible $\binom{n}{k}$ combinations with non-zero probability (but need not be 'adverserial'). Notice that this condition is also necessary: if there is just one combination that the referee never plays, Alice and Bob can do better! We also see that Alice playing a random strategy or not has no effect on the counting argument.

Conclusion: to be certain of a win, Alice and Bob need at least one message with $\lceil\log_2(n-k+2)\rceil - 1$ bits of information (and this bound can trivially be achieved).

---

This is however only minimizing the *maximal* message size. If you want the message size to be the lowest-possible on average against for example a referee playing uniformly, you need the techniques that @leonbloy suggested. If we consider a deterministic strategy $f$ for Alice, meaning on input $X=(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ she redirects Bob to the box with ID $f(X)$, then it might well be that not every ID has equal probability of being chosen. By agreeing on a renumbering of the boxes, Alice and Bob can make advantage of this by giving boxes with a high probability of being $f(X)$ a short message length.

The average number of bits needed with this strategy $f$ is best measured with the classical entropy-function $\sum{-p_i \log_2(p_i)}$ (if I'm not mistaken). Now we should minimize the entropy of the image of $f$. Some candidates for $f$ could be: $f(X) = \min(X)$, $f(X) = \text{median}(X)$,...
My experiments for small $n$ and $k$ show that the minimum-function is best on average among several $f$, but I don't know if this could be proven analytically.

Comment: You have an interesting interpretation that a max of $2$ bits allows you to have $7$ different messages.  However I think this interpretation is highly non-standard.  :)  In other words, the end-of-msg character (needed in your scheme) should count as part of the information content.  Anyway, welcome to MSE!

Comment: I agree that in the machine world, one almost always needs fixed message length or an end-of-message character, but in this game they are humans passing only one message. If for example Alice were to write down her message on a piece of paper, Bob could obviously see where it ends. It depends on the OP's opinion, but for me it seems just the right amount of thinking outside the box ;)